# Iinitlize vector like python in R

Tags: python, r, initialization

When I initialize list in Python I use one command format: `l=[func() for i in range(1,100)]`.
How can I initialize vector in R in a similar way?

edit: the function `func()` may be random.

Comment: Thanks, I did `v <- rep(0,100); for(i in 1:100) v[i] <- sample(4,1)` and the code works, are you sure that there is no more elegant way? I heard that "for loop" is less recommended then "vector loops" (like apply), this advice doesn't valid for mine situation?

Comment: are you looking for `l=sapply(seq(100),function(x) sample(4,1))` ? or `replicate(100,sample(4,1))` ?

Comment: Yes, replicate is very good. thanks both of you!

Comment: @BenBolker - I don't know Python, but where did you get that 4?  Is it arbitrary?

Comment: just using the OP's example (from the first comment)

Comment: By the way, for this specific example, `sample(1:4,size=100,replace=TRUE)` will give the same answer

Comment: ... and be much faster.

Comment: I know... I wanted to emphasize that f is randomized procedure. Thanks.